# Wrong kerning on Android with specific font

Tags: android, fonts, textview, kerning

I have to use the Futura font in my Android application. The futura OS X font is a ttc one. So I used dfontsplitter to split the .ttc font in many .ttf.
But when I apply one of those fonts to a TextView, the kerning is sometimes good, sometimes wrong. I think it depends on the density. I was able to find a font size which works on my hdpi devices and xhpdi devices but It still does not work on other densities.

api target: 17

Does that come from my font or my project. Is there a way to avoid that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I have to use the Futura font in my Android application" -- did you license the font? http://www.linotype.com/472/futura-family.html